# How to properly work with vectors of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector, memory-management

If I have a vector of objects, for example:

```
std::vector<Foo> foos;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    foos.push_back(Foo());
}
```

and lets say I distinguish them in different kind of `Bar`s, each with a vector of `Foo`s:

```
std::vector<Bar> bars;

bars.push_back(Bar());
bars.push_back(Bar());

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    bars.at(0).addFoo(foos.at(i));

for(int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
    bars.at(1).addFoo(foos.at(i));
```

If I now do for example `foos.at(0).setValue(1)`, `bars.at(0).getFoo(0).getValue()` would not be 1, so I have to create pointers:

```
std::vector<Bar> bars;

bars.push_back(Bar());
bars.push_back(Bar());

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    bars.at(0).addFoo(&foos.at(i));

for(int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
    bars.at(1).addFoo(&foos.at(i));
```

`bars.at(0).getFoo(0).getValue()` would now return 1.

But how do I clean those pointers properly?

- If I do `foos.pop_back()`, how can I make that automatically the last Foo pointer in `bars.at(1)` will get deleted? Because in my program I sometimes wouldn't know where in the `bars` vector the pointer to the exact object is.
- If I do `bars.at(1).removeLastFoo()`, the object would ofcourse (and also should) stay alive in `foos`. Would `removeLastFoo()` just delete the last pointer of `Bar`s vector of `Foo`s and pop it?
- If I do `bars.pop_back`, do I have to write in `Bar`s destructor to delete every single pointer out of it?

If I have forgotten something, please tell me.

Or is there a more elegant way (I actually prefer not to use pointers but I see no other way) to be able to see the same changes at different locations?

Comment: You don't, these pointers aren't stable. You may consider using a `std::list` instead.

Comment: @user0042 for what reason? And where would I use it? Instead of the `vector` of `Foo`s, the `vector` of `Bar`s or the internal `vector` of `Foo`s inside of the `Bar` class?

Comment: They aren't stable, because the memory management (of a contiguous array) is under control of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using C++11 you can use a combination of [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr):

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> foos;
```

And inside of Bar you would have a vector of weak_ptr:

```
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Foo>> foos_inside_bar;


for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    std::weak_ptr<Foo> weak_foo_ptr = foos.at(i);
    bars.at(0).addFoo(weak_foo_ptr);
}
```

If you do `foos.pop_back()` the `shared_ptr` in `foos` gets deleted and the the last `weak_ptr` in bars would [expire](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired).
If you remove the `weak_ptr` in `bars`, the `shared_ptr` in `foos` stays alive.

Comment: Works as it should. One thing I dislike though is that in `addFoo` you should first search for expired `weak_ptr`s  and delete them so your vector doesn't get longer and longer with expired pointers. But I'm okay with that as long as it doesn't take ages

Comment: That was also my concern, but I can't find a proper way of deleting the expired pointers, when a `foos.pop()` is done. At least not without messing up the code real hard :/

Answer (score 0):

In the end I fixed my problem by not adding any objects or pointers to `bars`. I modified the `Bar` class and instead of adding Foo objects or pointers I added their indexes from the original `foos` vector.

```
// create foos
std::vector<Foo> foos;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    foos.push_back(Foo());
}


// create bars
std::vector<Bar> bars;

bars.push_back(Bar());
bars.push_back(Bar());

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    bars.at(0).addFooIndex(i);

for(int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
    bars.at(1).addFooIndex(i);


// print & calculate
foos.at(0).setValue(1);
std::cout << foos.at(bars.at(0).getFirstIndex()).getValue() << std::endl; // prints 1

foos.at(bars.at(0).getFirstIndex()).setValue(2);
std::cout << foos.at(0).getValue() << std::endl; // prints 2
```